# How to compile sicktoolbox_wrapper2

Tags: ros, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the LMS511 laser scanner. After a deep search I found a recommended fork of the Sicktoolbox_wrapper2 at:  https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/laser_drivers

To install, from TerminaI I typed:
git clone https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/laser_drivers.git

then in catkin_ws: catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash

rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms5xx

gives the error:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sicklms5xx below /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper2

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Sam

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233623/how-to-compile-sicktoolbox_wrapper2/) by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-05-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-04**:
I realised I need to use rosbuild as in
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin

I've followed the tutorial and built the code but still get similar error:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sicklms5xx below /home/ros/rosbuild_ws/sicktoolbox2/sicktoolbox_wrapper2

### **Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-04**:
I do get the following error during the build process:
/bin/sh: 1: autoreconf: not found

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sicktoolbox2 written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/ros/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160504-

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2017-06-05**:
@Sam Wayne How did you solve this error ? rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms_5xx Attempting to connect to Sick LMS 5xx @ 192.168.0.1:2111 A Timeout Occurred - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: select() timeout! [ERROR] Initialize failed
I am also facing the same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are attempting to compile the package with Catkin, while it is a rosbuild one (legacy ROS build system). Please see the differences [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_or_rosbuild).

It is possible to make a rosbuild overlay workspace on top of your catkin workspace. Please read [Using robuild with catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin). Particularly pay attention to sections 3.3 and onwards.

P.S. Unfortunately I had no time to catkinize the package back in 2013 and now I have no access to the hardware to make sure everything works.

(it took me a while to understand I didn't press the Post button)

**EDIT**:

Regarding the autoconf. If you are on Ubuntu install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

**EDIT 2**:

I tried to reproduce the error you have mentioned in the comments, but almost everything worked fine. The only problem I can spot is that you are cloning the `laser_drivers` stack into `sicktoolbox2` directory, that seems to be wrong because the actual stack name is `laser_drivers`.

Make sure the workspaces were sourced correctly. To do that unset all ROS environment variables (the ones that have `ROS_` prefix) or simply comment the lines in your `.bashrc` file that source ROS workspace setups, e.g. `~/catkin/devel/setup.bash` (if you have any) and restart the terminal. Also remove the rosbuild workspace folder.

Then source catkin workspace:

```
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Create rosbuild overlay:

```
$ mkdir ~/rosbuild_ws
$ cd ~/rosbuild_ws
$ rosws init . ~/catkin_ws/devel
```

Add `laser_drivers` stack with `sicktoolbox2` to rosbuild overlay:

```
# Pay attention to the parameter after 'set' argument
$ rosws set laser_drivers --set https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/laser_drivers.git
$ rosws update laser_drivers
```

Source rosbuild overlay:

```
$ source ~/rosbuild_ws/setup.bash
```

Additionally, to make bash tab-completion work for downloaded packages and stacks:

```
$ rosstack profile
$ rospack profile
```

Finally, build the stack:

```
$ rosmake laser_drivers
```

In my case the last step failed to build `hokyo_node` package, but I think that can be ignored if you don't need it. The `sicktoolbox2` and `sicktoolbox_wrapper2` compiled without errors.

If you still encounter the problem with `download_checkmd5.py` after following the above steps, it might be necessary to reinstall ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-11**:
Thank you. I've now installed 'autoconf' ok.
When I  'rosmake sicktoolbox2 '

I get:
Build failures with context:
/bin/sh: 1: /opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py: not found
make: *** [build/rhuitl-sicktoolbox-7439818/trunk/unpacked] Error 127

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-11**:
in more detail:
rosws set sicktoolbox2 --git https://bitbucket.org/koreatech-ugv/laser_drivers.git

rosws update sicktoolbox2

rosmake sicktoolbox2

Builds with a failure looking for /bin/sh: 1: /opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py: not found

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-12**:
Dear Boris,
thank you for your detailed answer. I have now managed to compile it as you mentioned.
Could you please tell me how to run?
I've tried $ rosrun sicktoolbox2 sicklms5xx
but get:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sicklms5xx below /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox2

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-05-12**:
@sam-wane The ROS-nodes are in the wrapper package, so you have to run them with `rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms_5xx`

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-12**:
When I run the above, I get:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sicklms_5xx below /home/ros/rosbuild_ws/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper2

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-05-12**:
Did you actually run `rosmake laser_drivers`? This command should make whole stack (in rosbuild terms). If you did, then try to compile just the wrapper with `rosmake sicktoolbox_wrapper2`. rosmake usually builds in parallel, so it is possible the wrapper didn't compile because of `hokyo_node`.

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-05-13**:
Fantastic! It works I believe since it is trying to contact the laser, I will resolve setting the correct ip address next and then test it on the LMS511. Thank you so much for your patience!
I have just ordered the outdoor Hokuyo too as a back up plan too so can run that with the Hokuyo node

**Comment by [Sam Wane](https://answers.ros.org/users/316/sam-wane/) on 2016-06-09**:
Close, I've changed the ip address of Sick to 192.168.0.1 and can ping it, but I get the error when I run:
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms_5xx
Attempting to connect to Sick LMS 5xx @ 192.168.0.1:2111
A Timeout Occurred - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: select() timeout!
[ERROR]  Initialize failed

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-06-16**:
Unfortunately I can't help you with this as I don't have the device. Maybe try to connect to the device from Windows machine via proprietary SICK software and make sure the network settings match...

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2017-06-05**:
@Sam Wayne How did you solve this error ? rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms_5xx Attempting to connect to Sick LMS 5xx @ 192.168.0.1:2111 A Timeout Occurred - SickLMS5xx::_setupConnection: select() timeout! [ERROR] Initialize failed
I am also facing the same issue!